# Finding out the type of value passed is select statement or csv without using SQL predefined keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

Please provide help in this created procedure which when executes returns result as the value passed to parameter it is csv or it is `select`.

Here I used `select` in `like` statement to find out what value is passed. there is any way in which  without using any sql keyword I can identified whether passed parameter value is csv or it is `select`

```
Create procedure TypeOfvalue
(@abc varchar(max))
as 
begin
IF (@abc like '%select%')
begin
    Print 'It is select'
End
Else 
Begin
    Print 'It is CSV'
End
```

First:

```
Declare @abc varchar(max)
set @abc='1'
execute TypeOfvalue @abc
```

Output: "It is CSV"

Second:

```
Declare @abc varchar(max)
set @abc='select * from tbl1'
execute TypeOfvalue @abc
```

Output: "It is a Select"

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want. What do you mean with "without any sql keyword"? Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: I've provided my working code example with examples for tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `PARSEONLY` in combination with `NOEXEC` options for this. See this code example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #TypeOfvalue (@code nvarchar(max)) AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @result int

BEGIN TRY
    EXEC(N'SET PARSEONLY ON;SET NOEXEC ON;'+@code+N';SET NOEXEC OFF;SET PARSEONLY OFF;')

    PRINT(N'Statement')
    SET @result = 1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT(N'CSV')
    SET @result = 2
END CATCH

RETURN @result

END

GO
DECLARE @returnCode int

EXECUTE @returnCode = #TypeOfvalue @code = N'abc;'
SELECT @returnCode as returned -- 2 (CSV)

EXECUTE @returnCode = #TypeOfvalue @code = N'SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects'
SELECT @returnCode as returned

DROP PROCEDURE #TypeOfvalue -- 1 (SELECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

- [Source](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/T-SQL-Script-to-check-the-935002e7)

```
CREATE  PROC TestProc 
    @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN 

IF EXists ( 
SELECT 1 FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@SQL, NULL, 0) 
WHERE error_message IS NOT NULL 
AND error_number IS NOT NULL 
AND error_severity IS NOT NULL 
AND error_state IS NOT NULL 
AND error_type IS NOT NULL 
AND error_type_desc IS NOT NULL ) 
BEGIN 
    Print 'It is CSV' 
END 

ELSE  
BEGIN 
    Print 'It is Select'
END 

END 
GO
```

Note that this is check the validation it means that a valid `SELECT` statement not any input that have a `SELECT` keyword.
And also this will say input is valid for other valid statements like `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and etc.

Comment: Just a hint, this will work only at SQL Server 2012 and above. :-)

Comment: Thanks but I need this in oracle that is why looking for some generic code

Comment: @user2099433 Well, then tag your question as Oracle!

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu thats why looking for dsome generic code

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu we can find isnumeric equivalent in oracle